# Using CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT to limit image display to mobile devices

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using the following code line to determine if images should be displayed

```
<cfif NOT CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT contains "mobile"> 
  <img src="...
  ...
</cfif>
```

Works fine on my phone but I have one user using Safari on an iPhone where the code does not stop images being shown. Other users on iPhones have no issue. I wrote a test for her http://webworkwest.com/whatsMyUserAgent.cfm using the same USER_AGENT code and it IDs her phone.

Any ideas what would make that IF statement to fail?

Comment: Google “regex to detect mobile browser from user agent”. Using a regex would improve your detection, but will not be 100% fool proof. Or, you could implement something more complex using a library like browscap (https://browscap.org), which would be more accurate.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: @Jim Do you not want to show the image because it is too large to be viewed completely on a phone screen? Like it knocks the display out of whack? You might look at https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/ and https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset for browser support of different approaches to this issue.

Comment: I have banner images on the desktop version that I don't want to show on a mobile device because there is a form on the page. Without the banner image the form doesn't have to be scrolled.  The Coldfusion version number is 10.  The confusing aspect of this issue is that it doesn't happen with anyone else running the code...except the client!

Comment: @JimButchart Their phone's `HTTP_USER_AGENT` probably doesn't include "mobile". What kind of device are they using to view the page?

Comment: @Shawn The user is using an iPhone. I search for both "mobile" and iPhone in the cgi.http_user_agent (not shown above).  This is what the client's device reports as the user_agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

Comment: The problem with the accepted solution is that in 6 moths, it may be outdated. Might be a better solution to use media queries to simply hide the banner images on smaller resolution screens.

Comment: @ScottStroz Agreed. I edited my answer after Adrian's comment. I definitely think `HTTP_USER_AGENT` isn't accurate enough to reliably catch mobile screens. Media queries do a better job, but still aren't always perfect. Modernizr is probably overkill, since it does a lot more than just media queries. For this user, I don't think there is really one perfect answer, but it is important to remember that just because today's iPhone says so in the user_agent, doesn't mean that next version will. Or that the user won't change browsers. Or phones. :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** RE: The comment by Adrian Moreno: I totally missed the notice on the page that the last time the regex was updated was 1 August 2014. While that regex may catch a lot of mobile devices, it will probably miss some recent ones also. And as Adrian also noted, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` isn't really that accurate on many modern devices. Feature detection does a lot better job of determining what a browser *can* do, but can still have issues with some modern tablets. You can use something like Modernizr (https://modernizr.com) or you can still try to do device detection with something like WURFL (https://wurfl.io), and there is the HTML picture element (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element), but that's not supported by all browsers. It will really depend on what kind of responsiveness you need. I tend to do more back end dev than UI/UX, so others may be able to offer some more recent suggestions.

**ORIGINAL:**

This is *WAY* too long for a comment, but you can try using the scripts at DetectMobileBrowsers. It's simply a huge regex to find the different common identifiers in your `CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT` that's being reported. That said, it's trivially easy to spoof your User Agent so YMMV. And you should also provide your users a way to not view your Mobile-optimized view if they don't want to. You might also want to go through the list to validate what you're looking for.

I can't take credit for this one. That goes to the folks at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/.

```
<cfif reFindNoCase("(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino",CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)
OR reFindNoCase("1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-",Left(CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT,4))>

DO STUFF HERE

</cfif>
```

*NOTE: I apologize for the horizontal scrolling.*

There's also a very nice CFC put together by Giancarlo Gomez. https://github.com/GiancarloGomez/ColdFusion-MobileDetect/blob/master/MobileDetect.cfc. It doesn't seem to have been updated in a couple of years, so you may have to go through and check the detections. If you make changes, I'm sure he wouldn't mind a pull request. :-)

Comment: That site itself says the regex hasn't been updated since 2014. I don't think you can rely on anything of this sort anymore. The preferred method for showing or hiding content on mobile was CSS media queries, but modern phones have screens matching and eclipsing laptop screen resolutions and that is making media queries unreliable as well.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno I totally missed that note. Updated my answer. I do more back-end that front. Do you have any suggestions for image sizing?